# two OnMouseUp same time at one mouse click

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is my first project with unity.
i got one function OnMouseUp at my gameObject Chess.cs

```
private void OnMouseUp()
{
    GameController sc = gameController.GetComponent<GameController>();
    if (sc.GetGameOver() == false && sc.GetCurrentPlayer() == player)
    {
        DestroyMovePlates();
        InitiateMovePlates();
    }
}
```

and one function OnMouseUp at my gameObject moveplate.cs

```
public void OnMouseUp()
{
    GameObject cp = gameController.GetComponent<GameController>().GetPosition(matrixX, matrixY);
    Destroy(cp);
   // do something here
}
```

when i click on moveplate, function will destroy chess, but chess got MouseUp same time, i want OnMouseUp on chess will do after OnMouseUp on moveplate. please
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBwzw.png

this first time i use stackoverflow, and my english so bad. please help me.

Comment: Both the functions will be called at same time. An alternative would be, using Coroutines to call a function after a delay. So you can set a delay with Coroutine() or with Invoke() for the second OnMouseUp() function. This way you can control which function would run faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee the order in which these methods are called, so you can't be sure they will be called in the order you want.

What you could do instead is a raycast, and then call the methods in the collected objects on the order you want. You would need to use [RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) to collect more than one object. Then you could search the results for the components you want.

Also a warning, your `cp` variable does not seem to refer to a game object, since in the line above you are calling some `GetPosition` method.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class MouseListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            var hits = Physics.RaycastAll(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), 100.0f);
            Chess chess;
            MovePlate movePlate;
            for (var i = 0; i < hits.Length; ++i)
            {
                var temp = hits[i].collider.gameObject;
                if (chess == null) chess = temp.GetComponent<Chess>();
                if (movePlate == null) movePlate = temp.GetComponent<MovePlate>();
                if (chess != null && movePlate != null) break;
            }

            // Now the code could have either object, or neither, or both. If it has both, they will be called in the order you specify.
            if (movePlate!= null) movePlate.MouseUp(); // Note that I changed the name so Unity doesn't call this by itself
            if (chess!= null) chess.MouseUp(); // Same here
        }
    }
}
```